# Swipe to accept animation in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to create a swipe to accept gesture in SwiftUI.

[image: Black rectangle offset left on top of green rectangle]

For example, in this image, if you swipe to the left, a green rectangle would show and say something like "accepted". However, you can swipe right and the black rectangle would return to its original position.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I used DragGesture but it doesn't move the rectangle perfectly horizontal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a swipe to action button like this. You can customize and optimize code as per your requirement.

Tested in XCode 12.3 with iOS 14.3

```
typealias FrontView<V> = Group<V> where V:View
typealias BackView<V> = Group<V> where V:View

struct SwipeButton<Content: View, BackContent: View>: View {
    
    private var content: () -> TupleView<(FrontView<Content>, BackView<BackContent>)>
    @State private var offset = CGSize.zero
    
    private let onAction: () -> ()
    
    init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> TupleView<(FrontView<Content>, BackView<BackContent>)>, onAction: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.content = content
        self.onAction = onAction
        self.content = content
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        let (frontView, backView) = self.content().value
        
        return GeometryReader { (geometry) in
            ZStack {
                backView
                frontView
                    .offset(self.offset)
                    .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 30, coordinateSpace: .local)
                                .onChanged { gestrue in
                                    if gestrue.translation.width < 0  {
                                        self.offset.width = gestrue.translation.width
                                    }
                                    print(offset)
                                }
                                .onEnded { value in
                                    if value.translation.width < 0 {
                                        self.offset.width -= geometry.size.width
                                        onAction()
                                    }
                                }
                    )
            }
        }
        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .animation(.spring())
    }
}
```

Usage

```
struct SwipeDemoView: View {
    var body: some View {
        SwipeButton {
            // Add your fron view
            FrontView {
                Text("Swipe").frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity).background(Color.black).foregroundColor(Color.white)
            }
            // Add your back view
            BackView {
                Text("Accepted")
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
                    .background(Color.green)
            }
        } onAction: {
            print("Swiped...")
        }
        .frame(width: 200, height: 50)
        .cornerRadius(15)
    }
}
```

[image]